# Is it possible to get the complete file path of a class where the source code is located using coderush APIs?

Tags: visual-studio, coderush, dxcore

I wanted to get the full file path when the caret in visual studio is at object Creation or referring a method of some other class.

Something like

```
Class CurrentClass
{
   Class2 object1=new Class2();

   object1.method1();

}
```

Can I get the complete file path like    **c:\ProjectLocation\Class2.cs**.

When I get this line in visual studio.

```
Class2 object1=new Class2();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve the active expression (object creation expression, type reference expression, method reference expression), and get the file name with resolved declaration, using  code like this:

```
  Expression activeExpression = CodeRush.Source.Active as Expression;
  if (activeExpression!= null)
  {
    IElement declaration = activeExpression.Resolve(new SourceTreeResolver());
    if (declaration != null)
    {
      string fileName = declaration.FirstFile.Name;
      // use the fileName...
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am just trying to do few basic things with coderush like getting all methods in parent class...And i tried **Class** **parent=** **declaraton.GetDeclaration()** **as** **Class** and tried to use **parent.AllMethods**, this didnot give access to all methods in that class....I was trying with **TypeReferenceExpression** is there some other class or function that i need to see??

Comment: 'declaration' in our code should be an instance of ITypeElement type, so try to use code like this:

ITypeElement typeInstance = declaration as ITypeElement;
      if (typeInstance != null)
        foreach (IMemberElement member in typeInstance.Members)
        {
          IMethodElement method = member as IMethodElement;
          if (method != null)
          {
            // do something with method...
          }
        }